# Find a mistery number in a equation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers, find, equation

So i am learning Ruby and got stuck in one exercise. I need find a mistery number in a equation that is in a string.For example ('10 + ? = 18'). The course i am following ask to use eval. I know eval is dangerous, is just for learning purpose. I am using rspec to test, so dont need use if and return

All i got is this

```
class MisteryNumber
  def calculate(operation)
    count = 0
    expression = operation.split(' = ')
    expression[0].gsub!("?", "#{count}")
    (eval(expression[0] - eval(expression[1])
  end
end
```

this code only works if i have subtraction or addition equations. If the equation is like this ('100 / 5 * ? = 40'), doesnt work anymore. I tried to do some form of iterator using gsub(thats why i have the 'count' in the code) but no luck. How i could od this?

Comment: 0_0 Is there some kind of limitation in the possible operations or values of `?`? It seams impossible to resolve an equation without parsing it into an AST; and then what would be the point of using `eval`?

Comment: Was a tip to use eval with gsub, probably because they want people to avoid the use of parse or the shunting yard algorithm. I think the point is use brute force fo find that number

Comment: Your problem can be simple or extra-hard depending on what's really expected of you.
You have to give us more context: Are you supposed to search for an Integer solution? etc...

Comment: Yes, will be always be a first degrre equation with a integer solutio and the execise dont give us the range to test.. we need find out what integer would take the "?' spot and give the solution showed in the equation. Example. 10 + ? = 18,  ? would be 8.

Comment: ams there isnt no limitation about the range, one of the spec tests has the number 500000 as solution. One of the spec tests: expect(MisteryNumber.new.calculate('? + 5 * 2 = 500010')).to eq 500000

Comment: I posted a brute-force implementation using `eval`. I don't really like the code but it does the job. The extra being that it detects when there's no integer solution to the equation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that '?' appears at the end of the left side of the equality and that the equation has a solution (the equation is not, for example, (`'0 * ? = 1'`). Both of these assumptions could be relaxed at the expense of somewhat more complex code. I will leave it to the reader to make those adjustments if desired.

We can write the main method as follows.

```
def calc(str)
  str = str.gsub(/[ =]/, '') 
  (str = str.insert(0,'+')) if str.match?(/\A\d/)
  left_str, s, right_str = str.partition(/[\+\-\/\*]\?/)
  qop = s[0]
  left_str = reduce_left(left_str)
  coeff, right_val = shift_to_right(left_str, right_str.to_f)
  solve(coeff, right_val, qop)
end
```

For example,

```
calc "3 * 7 / 3 + 4 / 2 * ? = 12"
  #=> 2.5
calc "2 - 4 / 2 + 8 / 2 + ? = 20"
  #=> 16.0
```

---

Suppose

```
str = "3 * 7 / 3 + 4 / 2 * ? = 12"
```

The first two steps are to adjust the formatting to simplify the following operations.

```
str = str.gsub(/[ =]/, '') 
  #=> "3*7/3+4/2*?12"

(str = str.insert(0,'+')) if str.match?(/\A\d/)
  #=> "+3*7/3+4/2*?12"
```

Now we break the string into three pieces.

```
left_str, s, right_str = str.partition(/[\+\-\/\*]\?/)
  #=> ["+3*7/3+4/2", "*?", "12"]
```

so

```
left_str
  #=> "+3*7/3+4/2"
s #=> "*?"
right_str
  #=> "12"
```

and save for later:

```
qop = s[0]
  #=> "*"
```

The three regular expressions read as follows.

- `/[ =]/`: match a space or equals sign
- `/\A\d/`: match a digit at the beginning of the string
- `/[\+\-\/\*]\?/`: match a '+', '-', '/' or '*'

---

The next step is to remove `'*'` and `'/'` from `left_str`. We can do this iteratively until none remain. The following method removes one. This uses the following regular expression:

```
R = /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([\*\/])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

We can write this regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
R = /
    (            # begin capture group 1
      \d+        # match 1+ digits
      (?:\.\d+)  # match period followed by 1+ digits in a non-capture group
      ?          # make the non-capture group optional
    )            # end capture group 1
    (            # begin the capture group 2
      [\*\/]     # match one character in the character class  
    )            # end capture group 2
    (            # begin capture group 3
      \d+        # match 1+ digits
      (?:\.\d+)  # match period followed by 1+ digits in a non-capture group
      ?          # make the non-capture group optional
    )            # end capture group 3
  /x             # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
def reduce_left_once(left_str)
  left_str.gsub(R) { $1.to_f.public_send($2, $3.to_f) }
end
```

Note that `m` is a [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html) object.

We can test (where `left_str #=> "+3*7/3+4/2"`):

```
left_str = reduce_left_once(left_str)
  #=> "+21.0/3+2.0"
left_str = reduce_left_once(left_str)
  #=> "+7.0+2.0"
left_str = reduce_left_once(left_str)
  #=> "+7.0+2.0"
```

As no change was made in the last step we are finished with this operation. This can be operationalized with the following method.

```
def reduce_left(left_str)
  loop do
    new_left_str = reduce_left_once(left_str)
    break left_str if left_str == new_left_str
    left_str = new_left_str
  end
end
```

```
left_str = "+3*7/3+4/2"
left_str = reduce_left(left_str)
  #=> "+7.0+2.0"
```

---

The next step is to shift all terms but the last in `left_str` to the right of the equality and adjust the right side accordingly. If `qop` equals `'*'` or `'/'` the last term of `left_str` is `'?'`'s coefficient; else it will be shifted to the right in the last step.

```
def shift_to_right(left_str, right_val)
  *terms, coeff = left_str.scan(/[\+\-]\d+/)
  terms.each { |s| right_val -= s.to_f }
  [coeff.to_f, right_val]
end
```

```
left_str = "+7.0+2.0"
right_str = "12"
coeff, right_val = shift_to_right(left_str, right_str.to_f)
  #=> [2.0, 5.0]
```

So

```
coeff
  #=> 2.0
right_val
  #=> 5.0
```

At this point we have reduced the original expression to

```
2.0 * x = 5.0
```

and need to solve for `x`.

The regular expression `/[\+\-]\d+/` in `shift_to_right` matches `'+'` or `'-'` followed by one or more digits.

---

The last step is to solve this simple linear equation. Recall that we have computed `right_val #=> "12"` and `'?'`'s operator is given by `qop #=> "*"`.

```
def solve(coeff, right_val, qop)
  case qop
  when '+' then right_val - coeff
  when '-' then coeff - right_val
  when '*' then right_val/coeff
  else          right_val * coeff
  end
end
```

```
solve(coeff, right_val, qop)
  #=> 2.5
```

Note that most of these operations would be needed if `eval` were used.

Comment: For once you didn't follow the specs o_O ? How rare ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: what sort of course is it?! This is definitely not a task for beginners!

One option to solve this without a parser is using approximations. It will not work for all the possible equation, but will 100% work when the difference of left and right sides is a monotonic, continuous function and has a good chance working for a good part of not-monotonic but continuous functions as well.

```
left, right = operation.split('=')
  .map {|side| side.gsub('?', 'x')}
  .map {|str| ->(x) { eval str }}

diff = ->(x) { left.(x) - right.(x) }
```

The above code will transform given equation into two procs representing left and right side of the equation. We are now looking for such x that `diff.(x) == 0`.

Next we need to find any two numbers for which `diff.(a) * diff.(b) < 0`, so that `diff.(a)` and `diff.(b)` have different signs. I'd probably start from some reasonable start test numbers (might depend on the common examples given), like [0, 1]. If `diff.(0)` and `diff.(1)` have different sign, we move to next step, if not we move the boundaries (preferably exponentially) until we find such numbers. NOTE: as the equation might have no solutions,`diff >= 0`. However, the proposed approach will work for any monotonic, continuous functions.

Step 2. Having [a,b] such that `diff.(a)` and `diff.(b)` we basically start a binary search. We calculate `diff.((a+b)/2)` and, depending on its sign, we take either `a` or `b` so that new pair have opposite signs. We repeat the process until `diff.((a+b)/2)` is zero. If that was just maths, we would need to establish some precision, but here we already have precision of float, so we can assume that it will eventually happen.

So, this would be the process, I'll leave coding it to you. :) Good luck. And seriously, what course is it?

Comment: haha, is a begginers course but they drop some challenges. This is one of them. Probably the purpose is to make us go after more knowledge on our own